# Reformatting string using REGEX

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

I'm very new to sql! I have a question regarding the reformatting of a string:

At the moment I have a columns which give me the following results such as:

```
1a20b345c
1a20b
20b345c
```

(the number of characters is not always equal). Each number and letter is a combination (`1a, 20b, 345c`). I would like it to put the letter ahead of the numbers (instead of starting with the numbers) but keeping the same order in terms of combination. Such as:

```
a1b20c345
a1b20
b20c345
```

Does that make sense? I cannot seem to figure out how to segregate the letters from the numbers and then reorder them.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Teradata? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 1):

#### Teradata

```
select regexp_replace ('1a20b345c','(\d+)(\D+)','\2\1')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!